# How to mask input in groovy

Tags: groovy

How can I mask input from the command line? Basic use case: I want to enter a password when prompted, and I need to either see *'s or nothing at all.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since you can call Java libraries from Groovy, you may find your answer in the question [How to mask a password in Java 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108937/how-to-mask-a-password-in-java-5).

In short, use [`Console.readPassword()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html#readPassword%28%29) (Java 6 or later).

Comment: I get this when running even Console.readLine(): Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static java.io.Console.readLine() is applicable for argument types: () values: []

Comment: System.console().readLine() according to TFM http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html

Comment: System.console() doesn't exist in groovy. Trying to reference anything off of it throws a NPE: Caught: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method readLine() on null object

Comment: What was making System.console() fail was the faulty eclipse plugin... Works now via shell.