# How to mask a password in command line

Tags: java

I want to mask a password. I used System.console() but it is not better and sometimes it returns null. Is there any other way to stop echo and mask a password? I am new to java. So please can anyone explain how to do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to mask a password in Java 5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108937/how-to-mask-a-password-in-java-5)

Comment: I am telling without using System.console().readPassword()

Comment: There is no other way than using System.console().readPassword() unless you use native code.

Comment: I think you have to find out why System.console().readPassword() is returning null sometimes before asking its alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach would be to use Java 6's [Console readPassword()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html#readPassword%28%29) method.

This site has a good article on how to do it using Java 5. http://www.devdaily.com/java/edu/pj/pj010005/. Basically they wrap System.in with an InputStreamReader and read a line.

If you are on a Unix system, you could try running the system program `stty` with argument `-echo` before reading the program and the program `stty echo` afterwards.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("stty", "-echo");
pb.start().waitFor();
// Read the password here
pb = new ProcessBuilder("stty", "echo");
pb.start().waitFor();
```

Note that I have not tried this! Some `stty` programs are happy with it and some aren't (those that aren't need their *stdin* to come from `/dev/tty` to work right...)

Comment: @JKAUSHALYA, what you do mean by it's not working sometimes. What is not? And what do you expect in the first place?

Comment: @vineet I dont know why but sometimes it returns null. I want to mask a password in windows command line.

Comment: @JKAUSHALYA well, you might want to post code then. `Console.readPassword` should work unless you are using it incorrectly.

Comment: @JKAUSHALYA: That's because there is no console to connect to, thus a NullPointerException. This not a bug in eclipse because the programs are executed in a Shell. See this filed bug here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=122429