# String to asterisk, masking password

Tags: java, string, password-protection, masking

I'm creating this simple login code for an ATM machine.
You enter username and password and you logs in, that works just great. Since I'm not connecting to a database or an external text file and I've just got 1 user, it's just written plainly in the Java code. But when you enter the password "p4ss" I want it to be masked, so instead of seing it on the screen while typing you should see "* * * *" or " " just blank (Like when you enter pass on Linux).

Currently my code looks like this:

```
    String user;
    String pass;            
    System.out.print("User: ");
    user = Keyboard.readString();
    System.out.print("Pass: ");
    pass = Keyboard.readString();

    if ((user.equals("Admin")) && (pass.equals("p4ss")))            
    {       
        menu();      
    }    
    else
    {       
        out.println("Wrong username or password.");
    }
```

Would appreciate any help I could get.

Comment: What is the Keyboard class here? If you're writing code for an ATM, why on earth are you using System.out?

Comment: Stackoverflow has built-in security, when you type p4ss all I see is ****

Comment: Well it's just a login page, the keyboard class is so I can input the text. The system out is so I can see the output on the screen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to mask a password in Java 5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108937/how-to-mask-a-password-in-java-5)

Answer (score 2):

Michael, have a look at the description on Sun's website:
https://web.archive.org/web/20120214061606/http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Security/pwordmask

Or, if you're using Java 5 or newer, you can use this:
[How to mask a password in Java 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108937/how-to-mask-a-password-in-java-5)

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is a simulated ATM...

Dev has pointed out that password masking on the console **is** supported out of the box, so you can use that. However for anything but the most trivial of IO you'd be better off using Swing or a "curses-like" library:

- http://www.pitman.co.za/projects/charva/index.html
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacurses/

Comment: Password masking is supported out of the box in JavaSE 6 or newer as indicated in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's a special method `Console.readPassword()` for doing this, introduced in Java 6. You obviously couldn't run code like this on a real ATM, though! Swing has `JPasswordField` which lets you do this kind of masking in a GUI, and one could imagine a Swing-based ATM window.

Comment: The first part is incorrect, you can mask a password on the console in Java6 or newer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have JavaSE 6 or newer you can use [Console.readPassword()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html#readPassword%28%29)